# How is the secrecy of the Iota seed maintained on IoT devices?

Tags: iota-network, security, internet-of-things

Iota is intended to be deployed on IoT devices.

A problem with IoT devices is that they are placed in insecure locations, allowing attackers to gain physical access and perform advance/prolonged attacks without detection.

Under these condition, an attacker can obtain the seed and hence masquerade as the device.

I can't see anything in Iota that prevents this. Are there any mechanisms in place?

Comment: At least related: https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/697/could-a-sensor-be-hacked-to-steal-the-money-in-its-wallet

Comment: IMO, this out of scope (Iota is just the protocol). Better ask this kind of question on https://iot.stackexchange.com/ or https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I can't see anywhere that says that Iota is just a protocol - it's an ecosystem according to the foundation, no? Device capture is a big issue in IoT and distributed systems. Does Iota do anything to solve this?

Comment: _"IOTA is a protocol that achieves consensus on the state of matters in a network."_ [from iota.org](https://www.iota.org/the-foundation/our-vision). Iota, as a protocol, don't use the concept of seed. Similarly, the Bitcoin protocol don't say anything about the way to keep your keys secure. I just say that you shouldn't expect anything at protocol level regarding this issue. Security in IOT devices isn't specifically related to Iota, it's a more general problem.

Comment: Yet here: https://blog.iota.org/iota-first-chapter-synopsis-506fdf874437

"this ‘second stage’ is all about taking advantage of IOTA’s modular lightweight nature by extending usability through modules/platforms built on top of the underlying IOTA fundament."